# yum, rpm segmentation fault

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

After trying to install the date server with the help of the script here https://github.com/Lozy/danted I am now getting `Segmentation fault` when I am trying to run any yum or rpm command.
To rebuild the rpm database I run these commands (as root):

```
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*
rpm -vv --rebuilddb
```

But as the rpm command doesn't work I am not able to repair the rpm database.
What can I do now to fix the problems?

I am running CentOS release 6.5 (Final) 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: 1) hopefully this is a test system? 2) how are your backups? 3) what did that installation script do?

Comment: yes, it's a fresh server, nothing important. No idea what it did but one thing it's sure it crashed the machine.

Comment: This should be a warning to you: for any non-distribution thing you're installing, always test first on a non-critical machine and ensure you have a good backup.